# Create a SQL Update Command Dynamically in a Web Service

Tags: sql, web-services, sql-update

So I don't know if if this is possible, or even advisable, but I was trying to figure out how I could create a Update Command in my webservice that can be built dynamically by the user. Basically, the goal is that there is a table that has x amount of columns and a user should be able to update any number of columns, without having to pass null or the existing values for the columns that aren't being updated. For example, one person may want to run

```
UPDATE calendar_table
SET title = 'Some new Title'
WHERE (id = 12344)
```

And another user may want to perform this action instead

```
UPDATE calendar_table
SET title = 'New Event', type = 'Meeting', note = 'Meet with new client'
WHERE (id = 12344)
```

So below is what I was trying to use, but I keep getting an exception stating that there is a problem near "WHERE" which is making me believe that it's something with how I'm trying to treat the update string

```
String MyConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConnStr);
        SqlCommand Query = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.calendar_table " +
            "SET @newText " +
            "WHERE (id = @appointmentID)", connection);
        Query.Parameters.Add("@newText", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = note;
        Query.Parameters.Add("@appointmentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = appointment;
        Query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            Query.Dispose();
        }
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated since the only other option I can think of is just create the web service with all the possible values and then either pass the existing values that aren't being changed along with the values.

Comment: just do not use any parameters for "set" at all. create a query like this: Query = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.calendar_table " +
            "SET " + note +
            "WHERE (id = @appointmentID)", connection);

Comment: Usually, you can't use host-variables for prepared SQL Statements.  Note that dynamic SQL is the most 'dangerous' (in that you have the highest chance for SQL Injection).  What language/framework are you working in?  A number of them have a way to 'safely' build statements, doing something like `Query.UpdateColumn("note")`, etc (I have no idea what this looks like for you, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will assumedly know which fields will be set for a given update.  Therefore, you can dynamically add each field to the `SET` clause and to the `Parameters` collection.  Using parameters for each field also avoids the SQL-injection issues mentioned in the comments.

Based on the syntax of your sample code, I'm assuming it's C#.  Below is one way you could handle updating a variable, user-defined number of fields.

Assume that there are variables containing values that the user has input:  `userInputTitle`, `userInputType`, `userInputNote`, etc.

The `id` field is included in the `SET` clause to remove the question of whether or not to add a comma before each dynamically added field in the `SET` clause.  As a side effect of this, the update can be run even if the user hasn't defined any fields.

By the way, it's considered better practice to use `using` instead of explicitly trying to clean up objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface, so the example below is rewritten accordingly.  The using statements will close the connection and dispose of the connection and command.  Also, using `Parameters.AddWithValue()` avoids the need to specify the data types of the parameters.

I have not tested this code.

```
String MyConnStr =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnStr"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConnStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand Query = new SqlCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            Query.Connection = connection;
            String sql = "UPDATE dbo.calendar_table SET id = @appointmentID";
            // The has-field-been-updated-by-user logic below assumes the
            // fields are strings.  Different logic might be necessary
            // for other data types.
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(userInputTitle))
            {
                sql += ", title = @title";
                Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", userInputTitle);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(userInputType))
            {
                sql += ", type = @type";
                Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", userInputType);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(userInputNote))
            {
                sql += ", note = @note";
                Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", userInputNote);
            }
            // Additional fields...
            sql += " WHERE (id = @appointmentID)";
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appointmentID", appointmentID);
            Query.CommandText = sql;
            Query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks gmm, that did work and I just need to make a few adjustments for the different fields that can be updated but this is what I needed to make sure I was on the right track to avoid SQL Injections.